# Dell Inspiron 20 Touch Screen Right Click Ubuntu 14.04 64

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, dell, touchscreen, inspiron

I have been having problems finding a logical or one that works yet. I have a 10 point multi touch. I can't use some features but right click being the big one. Does anyone else have one of these that work or some that can help? I looked at this but not sure about my hardware. http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.com/2011/08/howto-linux-on-dell-inspiron-duo.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try upgrading your linux kernel:

Follow my video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kFRtJiwCRI

Be aware that upgrade kernel sometimes causes problem, in my case, if i upgrade to 3.18 RC8)newest to date) it shutdowns the entire system.

So, i've made a tutorial with the 3.18 RC3, not RC8, that works on 14.04.1 (official download) ubuntu.

hope it helps

I also have a touchscreen ultrabook and upgrading kernel makes working many things

Comment: It didn't exactly work. I lost my virtual box support in the kernel and it didn't change anything. I can use the screen to click and drag stuff but I cannot get it to right click or scroll in a browser.

Comment: I removed the new kernel and reverted. Everything works but still no right click or scroll ect........

Answer (score 0):

Opera, chrome, midori scrolling works for me;
firefox doesn't work;

right click pressing also doesn't work for me, there is still many incompatibility but i hope it gets working